# Android Virtual Device running very slow on Windows Server 2019 with intel haxm

Tags: android, nested, virtualization, windows-server, haxm

I'm trying to run an AVD (Android Studio 4.0) on a dedicated Windows Server 2019 (i7 4Core, 16Gb Ram). The vmx flag is enabled and haxm is installed and working. The AVD is very slow on every phone and every Android Version. Sometimes it won't even get past the Google Boot logo.

I read almost every thread on stackoverflow regarding this problem. I can't use hyper-v due to technical dependencies but it says intel haxm should actually be fast enough. I've searched for other processes maybe blocking intel haxm but there is none. There is also no antivirus blocking haxm.

I also disabled the option "Use detected ADB location" and everything else which is recommended.

Also, everytime I start the AVD it gives me this message:

"GPU Driver Issue"
"Your GPU driver information: 
GPU#1
MAKE1414
Model Microsoft Basic Render Driver
Device id 008c
Some users have experienced emulator stability issues with this driver version. As a result, were selecting a compatibility renderer. Please check with your manufacturer to see if there is an updated driver available."

There is no graphics card installed and besides that I installed every driver correctly.

Does anyone have an idea?
Thank you.